# Naming a table that describes the movement of cryovials

Tags: word-usage, translation

I've got a document that describes the establishment of a cell bank. At the very end of this document, there's an unfilled table, a template. The personnel will add a line to this table each time a vial with material is removed from this frozen cell bank, in order to be thawed and used.

The Russian name for this table is simply "Movement" (Движение) - one can see the analogy here with "[stock movement](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=stock%20movement)" (withdrawal of different items from a storage facility, which is also reflected in a log).

Would an English speaker understand this title, "Movement"?

I came up with alternatives like "Cell bank usage log" or simply "Usage log" or "Usage history", but I'm curious to know whether "movement" will be comprehensible.

Here's what the head of the table looks like:

[image]

Basically, I'm curious whether **movement** is as instantly recognized as part of a stock phrase in English officialese as it is in Russian.

Comment: No, "movement" is too general.  "Vial removal log" perhaps.

Comment: The term movement is only used when something is simply being moved from one place to another. For example, the term **movement order** can be used to describe the paperwork to be completed when a group of soldiers, a farm animal or an abnormally large load are to be moved from one place or another. It would normally specify both 'from' and 'to' locations.

Comment: Here's the analogous pattern: http://www.gwumc.edu/research/labsafety/cold_trash_exempt_log.pdf  Substitute for "disposal" whatever noun best describes the activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Removal', 'movement' etc all seem slightly vague to me, as this doesn't narrow down whether the vial is being used, moved temporarily, moved permanently to another location, being destroyed, etc.

> The personnel will add a line to this table each time a vial with
>   material is removed from this frozen cell bank, in order to be **thawed
>   and used**.

*'Thawed and used'* is the key term for me here, as it's permanent - there is no going back once this action takes place. Therefore 'Usage Log' would be the most appropriate term in this position, in my opinion.